# Error in creating Line D3.js Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Js line Chart and i am able to draw chart.While i am using json data I am getting:

> Error: Cannot read property 'length' of null(…)

My function is like. i am getting error while parsing data. I am getting json response correctly, but I am enable to draw a chart. Can anyone tell me what is wrong i am doing?

```
                var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
               width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
               height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // Parse the date / time
                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;


                // Set the ranges
                var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

                // Define the axes
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                    .orient("left").ticks(20);

                // Define the line
                var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return x(d.dategraph); })
                    .y(function (d) { return y(d.assetcount); });

                // Adds the svg canvas
                var svg = d3.select("linegrapg")
                    .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                        .attr("transform",
                              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


 var dataset = [{"dategraph":"16-Nov-16","assetcount":299},{"dategraph":"19-Nov-16","assetcount":0},
                 {"dategraph":"08-Nov-16","assetcount":18},{"dategraph":"14-Nov-16","assetcount":10},
                 {"dategraph":"17-Nov-16","assetcount":2},{"dategraph":"18-Nov-16","assetcount":0}]
                data = JSON.parse(dataset.d);
                    data.forEach(function (d) {
                        d.Letter = parseDate(d.dategraph);
                        d.Freq = +d.assetcount;
                    });

                    // Scale the range of the data
                    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.Letter; }));
                    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Freq; })]);

                    // Add the valueline path.
                    svg.append("path")
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .attr("d", valueline(data));

                    // Add the X Axis
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                        .call(xAxis);

                    // Add the Y Axis
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .call(yAxis);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Update your question with the contents of `dataset.d`.  Otherwise it's impossible to answer...

Comment: Hellow i am updated my question with data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, the code runs by commenting out the JSON.parse function call and the two trailing curly braces. The data variable is already an array of objects so there is no need to de-serialize it (from a string type). Other than that, I wasn't able to reproduce the error you were getting. Have a look at the code snippet below.

```js
 var margin = {
     top: 30,
     right: 20,
     bottom: 30,
     left: 50
   },
   width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 // Parse the date / time
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;


 // Set the ranges
 var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

 // Define the axes
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
   .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
   .orient("left").ticks(20);

 // Define the line
 var valueline = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) {
     return x(d.dategraph);
   })
   .y(function(d) {
     return y(d.assetcount);
   });

 // Adds the svg canvas
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
   "dategraph": "16-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 299
 }, {
   "dategraph": "19-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 0
 }, {
   "dategraph": "08-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 18
 }, {
   "dategraph": "14-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 10
 }, {
   "dategraph": "17-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 2
 }, {
   "dategraph": "18-Nov-16",
   "assetcount": 0
 }];

 //var data = JSON.parse(dataset);

 data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.Letter = parseDate(d.dategraph);
   d.Freq = +d.assetcount;
 });

 // Scale the range of the data
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
   return d.Letter;
 }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
   return d.Freq;
 })]);

 // Add the valueline path.
 svg.append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", valueline(data));

 // Add the X Axis
 svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

 // Add the Y Axis
 svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Working Example with tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tip {   
       position: absolute;          
    text-align: center;         
    width: auto;            
    height: auto;               
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: black;  
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;   
    color:white;        
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; 
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
  var data = [
                  {"date":"08-Nov-16","close":299},
                  {"date":"09-Nov-16","close":10},
                  {"date":"10-Nov-16","close":18},
                  {"date":"11-Nov-16","close":10},
                  {"date":"12-Nov-16","close":2},
                  {"date":"13-Nov-16","close":50}];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 5)       
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);



</script>
</body>
```